# QGIS Join attribute by most similar lines

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

Using QGIS 3's (new?) Join attributes by nearest feature on two multiline layers, I get unexpected results... Namely, if a line crosses another, that is favored over one that is almost exactly the same, but shifted slightly:

[image]

While this seems like unexpected results to me, I may be doing it wrong... is there a "Join attributes by most similar" tool that will get what I'm looking for and match the two parallel lines over the two perpendicular ones?

Comment: If two features intersect, they're closer than any features which are separated - basic geometry. You could get the centroids/middle points of the lines, then search for the nearest feature, then join the attributes back to the lines.

Comment: But even then, two perpendicular lines that intersect near their midpoints would be "closer" than two lines that parallel. Is there some way to average the closeness of every point along each line to find the most "similar" lines.

Comment: For the time being, I'd be (mostly) happy with a algorithm that matches two lines based on the closeness of their start and end points...

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/336984/similarity-of-shapes-in-qgis-3-x/337003 - maybe it helps?